# JSON parse/stringfy adding extra data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm importing json file like below and converting it to string after it is parsed:

```
const obj = require('test.json')
const downloadable = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

However, the downloadable variable above contains extra properties like below which the original json file doesn't have

```
"__fnct": [
            null
          ]
```

and

```
"_render": true
```

What is happening and how can I get the original JSON file content back?

Comment: whats in ur test.json file can u show plz

Comment: By reading the file during runtime using a module like `fs` and then parsing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to load your file during runtime and then parse it using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

const jsonString = readFileSync('test.json').toString()
//.toString() converts the returned Buffer to a string

const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

const downloadable = JSON.stringify(obj);
```